# Launchpad dailybuild source in subdirectory of branch

Tags: launchpad, debian, bazaar, makefile, recipe

I have a repo branch that i have mirrored in Launchpad that I am trying to setup a daily build. The problem is that the source directory of the package is a subdirectory in the branch.  When building locally it's no problem because I can just change to that directory. However with launchpad's bzr-builder it does everything from the top directory in the branch.

My current build recipe is:

```
# bzr-builder format 0.3 deb-version {debupstream}-{revno}-{revno:packaging}
lp:kegbot
nest-part packaging lp:~szechyjs/kegbot/kegbot_debian debian debian
```

Ideally I would use `lp:kegbot/pykeg` but this is not possible in bzr.

Is there a easy way I can build the package in the kegbot/pykeg directory, by setting it up in my recipe or some kind of source directory variable in the rules file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this from the recipe itself.

I would recommend doing the replacemented of . with pykeg from within debian/rules.

Comment: Before I monkey around with some scripting to do this, any suggestions on how to do this from the rules file?

Comment: It really depends on the package itself. The simplest thing would be to just cd to pykeg before e.g. running configure and make.